# Admin privileges requiring for installing a package build though Packages

Tags: macos, package-management

Using osx 10.9 and packages for making package installer.

While installing a package made using **Packages** in **/Applications** location on a osx 10.9 machine, installer is asking for **Admin password**. Even though I had unchecked 'Require admin password for installation' while package making.

So, how to avoid this i.e a non-admin user should install this package. Package should install in /Applications location, so that non-admin user can use the app.

I check [this](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/tech_specs.html) and [this](http://simx.me/technonova/tips/packagemaker_and_installer.html)

Comment: If everything You need goes into one bundle inside `/Applications` dir, why don't You pack Your `.app` file inside dmg, so user could just drag and drop Your app?

Comment: There is a folder myapp which contains a)a.app b)b.app So I made package of this myapp folder which installs in /Application location. So in /Applications location myapp folder installs through myapp.pkg.

Comment: So are you saying to make dmg of this myapp folder. how please xplain

Comment: Using `hdiutil` command. Here's more info about this. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50040/74657 You can drag'n'drop this folder to `/Applications` without admin password.

Comment: Here's explanation how You can make custom backgrounds inside `dmg` file: https://el-tramo.be/guides/fancy-dmg/

Comment: Thanks @MateuszSzlosek. I created dmg. But when drag and droping the contains dmg i.e. myapp folder, non-admin user requires admin privileges. So again the same issue.

Comment: In /Applications location, drag and drop also requires admins privileges. So same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The installer is actually doing the right thing by asking for an admin password. Users without admin rights do not have the ability to write to the **/Applications** directory on a Mac.

Without knowing more about your installer, I suspect the request for an admin password is coming from Apple's **Installer.app**, which is the application that your installer is working with to install your application.

**Installer.app** is detecting that the non-admin account that's running the installation doesn't have admin rights and that **/Applications** doesn't allow non-admin users to write to it. To resolve the issue, **Installer.app** is requesting that an admin account authenticate the installation and authorize the needed rights. Otherwise, the installation will just fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere In your package you hav checked require admin authentication.
I have tested on 10.9 its not asking for password.

Comment: Which package are you using for installer making. I am using Packages. Application should be install in /Application location. It is asking password for both admin and non-admin users. Also I had not checked the require admin button.

Comment: I am using Package Maker

Comment: Are you installing package in /Applications location.

Comment: Yes , i am installing package inside Applications