# Downloading an application without the admin password

Tags: applications, mac-mini

I am a standard user of a Mac Mini. There are certain applications I would like to download from the web, but they require the Apple installer, which then requires the admin password. Is there any way I could circumvent this?

Comment: AFIK there is NO other way.

Comment: What do you mm wan by the apple installer?

Comment: @allan The question here seems to be about .pkg installers downloaded from a website, not about applications installed from the store.

Comment: @nohillside - I saw it as the same, but if it's about .pkg files, there's this Q/A:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163064/admin-privileges-requiring-for-installing-a-package-build-though-packages/163420#163420

Comment: You can install them on a different computer and move them over using a thumb drive

Comment: Either that, or reboot from an external macOS drive, and change the install location to the desired drive

Comment: @Sam wouldn't moving it from a USB require an admin password to execute the program?

Comment: It shouldn't in my experience

Comment: Ah, I realize what you mean. I tried installing on the same computer onto the USB. Instead, I should fully install on a different computer then transfer.

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of the OS requesting authorisation is to prevent software being installed without permission. If there were a method of bypassing the request, that would be considered a 'security flaw' and Apple would (hopefully) fix it quickly.

If you are not the actual owner of the Mac, then you need to ask the owner for permission to install the software.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have an account with admin privileges you can just fill in the name and password of the admin account even if you are logged in with your standard account. 
You can not circumvent the question for admin password for security reasons as benwiggy said.