# How to make a modified dmg distributable?

Tags: disk-utility, install, mount, firefox, dmg

**Adding files to a dmg and redistribute it**

**Purpose :**

Adding some settings files to [firefox.dmg](https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/63.0.3/mac/en-US/Firefox%2063.0.3.dmg) (mozilla.cfg and policies.json) in the objective of redistributing the modified dmg

**How the dmg is modified :**

- Decompressing the dmg with tools like (hdiutils/ultraiso/transmac/dropdmg/disk-utilities)
- Mounting and adding files to the decompressed dmg
- Optional (recompress the dmg with same utils used to decompress)

**Issue :**

Opening the new dmg in a different machine give the result `"firefox" is damaged and can't be opened, you should move it to trash`

**What was tested :**

- Removing `com.apple.quarantine` attribute with the command `xattr -c` **works but** its not a reliable solution
- Tried to remove `_CodeSignature` directories from the dmg without success
- Creating a new dmg containing files of the previous one without success
- Tried to edit Info.plist without success

**Question :**

How to make the new dmg package usable in other machines ? (How to avoid the error from gatekeeper without using `xattr -c`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Apple DMG Code Signing :**

Signing apple application require paying apple's developer program (99$), it can be done freely but for a limited purpose.

Signing dmg can be done in two ways :

- Signing the dmg file itself
- Signing the `Application.app` directory inside the dmg image

**Editing signed DMG files :**

Here is 3 possibles ways to edit signed applications :

1. Resign the application after edition
2. Remove the signature completely and edit the application (the application will still be installable the user will be warned)
3. Removing `com.apple.quarantine` attribute with the command `xattr -c` after editing the application

**Signature verification :**

Depending on the situation one or both commands are required

```
codesign -v Application.app
codesign -v Application.dmg
```

**Removing application signature**

After extracting the dmg etc. Depending on the situation one or both commands are required

```
codesign --remove-signature Application.app
codesign --remove-signature Application.dmg
```

**Explaining the failure :**

The `Application is damaged and can't be opened, you should move it to trash` is the result of a partial signature removal, because removing `_CodeSignature` directories is not enough to get rid of the signature; `codesign --remove-signature` needs to also be run against the package/application/binary

**Related lecture :**

[Create dmg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367751/creating-a-dmg) - [Create dmg from directory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48414/how-do-i-create-a-dmg-file-from-a-directory) - [Add signature to dmg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824815/how-to-add-codesigning-to-dmg-file-in-mac) - [Remove signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500381/bug-in-codesign-remove-signature-feature) - [Damaged application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458027/mac-dmg-oddity-signing-and-damaged-applications) - [How to code sign](https://ohanaware.com/support/v5Pages/how-to-code-sign-dmg-files.html) - [Free developer](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/12/24/how-to-create-a-free-apple-developer-account-xcode/) - [Free signature](http://www.applicationloader.net/blog/en/1135.html)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify the DMG and have it still pass trough GateKeeper without re-signing it. This is basically the entire reason for having the code signature!

Basically you have three options:

1) Remove the old code signature and re-sign the DMG with your own signature. This requires you to be enrolled in Apple's Developer Program.

2) Distribute the original, unmodified DMG - and accompany it with your own modifications. This could be done as instructions for the user on what to copy over, or it could be in the form of an automatic script.

3) Remove the signatures completely (both from the DMG and the app). The user then needs to have GateKeeper set to allow opening unsigned applications (i.e. the user will be prompted on the first open).

Comment: Unsigned DMG's aren't allowed on systems with Gatekeeper enabled anymore? I thought it was just apps themselves that needed to be signed.

Comment: If the developer signs the DMG, then the app can use files from that DMG. If the developer does not sign the DMG, then the app will be prevented from accessing the contents of the DMG by the way of relative file names. So if the program is designed to be installed from such a signed DMG where it uses files in the DMG, it won't work if you place it in a non-signed DMG.

Comment: As installing unsigned application is still possible when accepting the dialog 'unidentified developer...' how can i remove the signature from firefox other than removing _CodeSignature directory or rebuilding ? (i don't want to publish it in the appstore but just make it usable while copying it to other machines)

Comment: You've just described the only two ways of removing the signature, and then you say you do not want to do that. You have no other options. If you want to remove the code signature, you can do so by removing it.

Comment: Thank you for answers it's appreciated, sorry i was not clear what i meant is after removing "_CodeSignature" gatekeeper still detect that firefox.dmg is damaged, how can i get it to pop up the 'unidentified developer...'  dialog instead of the the damaged dialog ?

Comment: @jksoegaard I assume the goal is not to run the application *from* the dmg, but rather for the user to mount the dmg and then copy the app to /Appilcations (or another folder on the main hard disk). Why, then, does the DMG need to be signed?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy signature let gatekeeper trust the application, and thus when its copied to /Application gatekeeper know that it came from a signed dmg. and if settings are set to block unsigned application then even after copying it when the dmg is not signed running the copied version is impossible

Comment: And YES WE CAN edit an application and have it pass trough GateKeeper without re-signing it !

Comment: @intika Yes, I also wrote that to you earlier in my comments. If you remove the signature completely, you can run it. But you would have to allow running unsigned applications for GateKeeper to accept it.