# Compress $HOME Directory Using tar.bz2 | macOS 10.15.7

Tags: backup, command-line, external-disk, archive, compression

Not interested in using Time Machine in this case.

Trying to backup the $HOME directory and am producing an error at the same location no matter the command so far:

> `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/DataVaults: Cannot stat: Operation not permitted`

The approaches I've attempted with so far are the following:

1. `sudo tar -jcvf /Volumes/passport/michael_catalina.tar.bz2 .`
2. `sudo ditto -jV --keepParent --arch /Volumes/passport/home_catalina`
3. `sudo rsync -Paz -EH . /Volumes/passport/michael_catalina.tar.bz2`

   3a. `sudo rsync -Pa -EH . /Volumes/passport/michael_catalina.tar.bz2 --exclude ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/DataVaults`

   3b. `sudo rsync -Pa -EH . /Volumes/passport/michael_catalina.tar.bz2 --exclude ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data`

   3c. `sudo rsync -Pa -EH . /Volumes/passport/michael_catalina.tar.bz2 --exclude ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail`
4. `sudo tar -jcvf /Volumes/passport/michael_catalina.tar.bz2 . --no-mac-metadata`

I've also tried the above in Recovery Mode.

Comment: Will this help: [How do I create a DMG file from a directory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48414/how-do-i-create-a-dmg-file-from-a-directory) Otherwise, have you tried disabling SIP?